# how to make the ndk-debugger overlook the source from includes

Tags: debugging, android-ndk, gdb

how to make the ndk-debugger overlook the source from includes . My ndk-debug session halts at epoll_wait. It says no source available . Obviously this happens because this is only a include file in the /include/sys/epoll.h . How can I make the ndk-debugger to skip such stupid halts and go with the code to tell me where the code is running. My code should continue and overlook this and know that this is a include file. I cant provide all include file source code while debugging right. But my debugging session should not halt at such things. Please let me know if there is a solution.